# mysqli connection variable visible to all functions?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have config.php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);
```

I include this config.php in all my website pages.
eg

index.php

```
include("config.php");
include("functions.php");
...
```

in functions.php I have functions like this:

```
function get_name{
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=?");
}
```

my problem is, function get_name cant see $mysqli var. I need to include config.php inside get_name function (and all functions).

is there any other way to get $mysqli variable without need to include config.php in all functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global for variables in functions.

```
function get_name{
    global $mysqli;
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=?");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class and objects for this. In config page write down the connection variables & by including the config page in a database class, write your functions in an inherited class then pass it in an object based reference to functions.